# Compiling on Windows with clang produces strange errors

Tags: c, clang, llvm

I'm trying to make a simple program that creates a message box to compile with clang on windows

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    MessageBoxA(0, "text", "title", 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Clang initially says that it can't find Windows.h, but when I supply `C:\MinGW\include` with `-I`, it produces a number of errors that seem to suggest that clang can't correctly preprocess c.

```
C:\MinGW\include\winsock2.h:545:47: error: expected function body after function declarator
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE DECLARE_STDCALL_P(char *) inet_ntoa(struct in_addr);
                                              ^
C:\MinGW\include\winsock2.h:554:57: error: expected function body after function declarator
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE DECLARE_STDCALL_P(struct hostent *) gethostbyaddr(const char*,int,int);
                                                        ^
C:\MinGW\include\winsock2.h:555:57: error: expected function body after function declarator
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE DECLARE_STDCALL_P(struct hostent *) gethostbyname(const char*);
                                                        ^
C:\MinGW\include\winsock2.h:556:57: error: expected function body after function declarator
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE DECLARE_STDCALL_P(struct servent *) getservbyport(int,const char*);
                                                        ^
C:\MinGW\include\winsock2.h:557:57: error: expected function body after function declarator
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE DECLARE_STDCALL_P(struct servent *) getservbyname(const char*,const char*);
                                                        ^
C:\MinGW\include\winsock2.h:558:58: error: expected function body after function declarator
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE DECLARE_STDCALL_P(struct protoent *) getprotobynumber(int);
                                                         ^
C:\MinGW\include\winsock2.h:559:58: error: expected function body after function declarator
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE DECLARE_STDCALL_P(struct protoent *) getprotobyname(const char*);
                                                         ^
1 warning and 16 errors generated.
```

Is there something I should try or is clang just not mature enough on windows?

Comment: The compiler thinks that `DECLARE_STDCALL_P` is a function name and `(char *)` is the argument list. That has everything to do with the include files and include paths that you're giving the compiler, and nothing to do with the compiler itself. If you want this to work, you need to find the installation guide that tells you how to set things up correctly.

Comment: @user3386109 I've looked for the installation instructions, but all I've found are instructions to install the visual studio plugin, which I don't want. Do you have a link?

Comment: Nope, I use visual studio on windows, and clang on the Mac. My point is that you can't just pull a compiler out of thin air, and expect it to work on a system it wasn't designed for. Whoever or wherever you got that compiler needs to give you either the instructions or installation tool to set it up correctly.

Comment: @user3386109 Yep, built llvm and clang from source following http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html and I'm getting the exact same errors.